# Why is last element of an array only being populated for onClick in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looping through an array of objects and i'm experiencing strange behavior. Here is my code:

```
  window.onload = function () {

    document.getElementById('btnAdd').onclick = function () {
        add("button");
    };
    function add(type) {
        var names = {};
        names['one'] = { id: "Button 1",msg:"#1" };
        names['two'] = { id: "Button 2", msg: "#2" };
        names['three'] = { id: "Button 3", msg: "#3" };
        //Create an input type dynamically.
        function addOnClick(element, currentName) {
              element.onClick = function () {
                 alert("button is " + names[currentName].msg);
            };
          };       

        for (name in names) {
            var element = document.createElement("input");

            element.type = type;
            element.value = names[name].id; 
            element.name = name;  
             addOnClick(element,name);

            var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
            //Append the element in page (in span).  
            foo.appendChild(element);
        }
    }
};
```

Heres the html:

```
 <p>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Buttons" />
<p id="fooBar">Buttons:   </p>

</p>
```

If you run this in your browser, and the "Add Buttons" button, 3 buttons are created and named appropriately. But if you click one of the 3 new buttons, the alert box always says "button is #3" and i have no idea why. Can someone explain why the onClick event is only remembering the last item in my array? Thanks

Comment: Why not make your names object an array?

Comment: I tried that, but i got the same results, so i omitted it.

Comment: it's `element.onclick` not `element.onClick`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are falling prey to the rules of closure capture in javascript.  There is only one copy of `name` and when `onclick` fires it will be the last `name` value in the collection `names`.  In order to solve this you need to create a new `function` scope that captures the current value of `name`

```
var addOnClick = function(currentName) { 
  element.onclick = function() { 
    alert("button is " + names[currentName].msg);
  };
};
addOnClick(name);
```

**EDIT**

You also need to use `onclick` not `onClick`.  Case matters here

> Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nzf3p/

Comment: Thanks for replying. I updated my code above, but no popup appears.

Comment: @user1202717 you also had an issue with `onclick` vs. `onClick`.  I updated my answer and linked to a fiddle

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the way that closures work in Javascript (capture of local variables). The anonymous function that is assigned to `element.onclick` is:

```
function () { 
    // Note this is a function
    alert("button is "+ names[name].msg);
};
```

Here, the value of `name` is bound to the last value that is encountered in the loop, which is the last element. Essentially `name` in the loop points to a memory location that is used by `name` in the outer loop. That location is constantly updated and at the end, points to the value `three`. To get around this, you need an additional function (which creates a new scope) to preserve the value of `name`. This creates a version of `name` that is local to that new function and therefore preserved:

```
//A self-invoked function, into which you pass name. preservedName is the preserved
//value of name, which is local to the scope of this self-invoked function.
(function(preservedName) {
    element.onclick = function() {
        alert("button is " + names[preservedName].msg);
    };
})(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the closure you're creating for the onclick handler.

```
element.onclick = function () { // Note this is a function
            alert("button is "+ names[name].msg);
        };
```

Should be wrapped by a function that passes in the name you're interested in:

```
addOnClickToElement(element,name);
```

Then add this named function at the same scope as 'add' so that `names` is accessible:

```
function addOnClickToElement(element,name) { // Note this is a function
    element.onclick = function(){alert("button is "+ names[name].msg);};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm close but not quite there. I updated my code above

Comment: I commented on your question, but i'll also do it here -- it's `element.onclick` not `element.onClick`